# Global existence ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a question regarding the exercise below. Sorry if I am not writing it in LaTex but it would be a mess to rewrite all this. I do not understand why, at point b) the author writes: We surely have global existence for all initial $k_0 ∈ [0,k_2]$ while this is not guaranteed for $k_0 > k_2$. Why is this true?

[image]

Comment: I removed the stochastic calculus tag because it has no relevance here. Do you know conditions under which you have global existence? Do you know any examples where global existence fails? Can you see why they resemble the case $k_0 > \bar{k}_2$?

Comment: Global existence means that a particilar solution holds for any $t \in T$. Perhaps here he is referring to the fact that we have global existence at least at right for every $ t \in T$ because any solution converges to $k_2,k_1,k_0$ in finite or infinite time. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order *not* to have global existence, the solution $k(t)$ would have to blow up in finite time. But if the solution starts in the interval $[0,k_2]$, it can't get out of that interval (since it can't cross the equilibrium solutions), so that can't happen.

On the other hand, if you start to the right of $k_2$ it may perhaps happen that $k(t) \nearrow +\infty$ as $k \nearrow T$, for some finite time $T$.